# Images not loading in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For a small project I am doing, I am creating a masonry style picture board using `css3` column count.
This works perfectly and creates the 4 columns I want to use.

My problem is is that the images that populate the cards only render in the 1st column. In the rest, they are their, and if i `click` and `drag` or right click it provides the image url/the `thumbnail`. In `firefox` and `internet explorer` this renders correctly and images show in every column, just not on chrome.

The **html** for my pictures is as below:

```
<div class="col s12 masonry">
    <div class="masonryItem card" ng-repeat="photo in RecentPhotos">

        <div class="card-image">
            <img ng-src="Assets/images/Photos/{{photo.fileName}}">
            <span class="card-title" ng-hide="photo.editing">{{photo.name}}</span>
            <input class="card-title" title="Title" type="text" ng-model="photo.name" ng-show="photo.editing" ng-blur="updatePhoto(photo)" autofocus/>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
            <p ng-hide="photo.editing">
                {{photo.description}}
            </p>
            <input title="Description" type="text" ng-model="photo.description" ng-show="photo.editing" ng-blur="updatePhoto(photo)" autofocus/>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action">
            <a href="" ng-click="editPhoto(photo)">Edit</a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

The **css** for the `masonry` classes is as below:

```
.masonry {
 /* Masonry container */
    column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    column-gap: 1em;
    -moz-column-gap: 1.5em;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1.5em;
    column-fill: auto;
    -moz-column-fill: auto;
    -webkit-column-fill: auto;
}

.masonryItem {
 /* Masonry bricks or child elements */
    background-color: #eee;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Unfortunately i cannot upload a screenshot on here, so cannot show you my actual site however this **[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cLbgjvxz/)**

Demonstrates the problem.
although images aren't actually on there, you can see that the first column has the 'broken image' link but the rest do not despite having images linked in them.

Comment: Please check console logs. I can see so many errors related to loading images. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Can you please provide jsfiddle without any console error. Its seems the images that you are specifying are not available.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `overflow: hidden` from `.card` class

```
.card {
    position: relative;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    margin: 0.5rem 0 1rem 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: box-shadow .25s;
    border-radius: 2px; 
}
```